# PHP Memcached's OPT_PREFIX_KEY Not Being Applied

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I've got this code:

```
$connection = new memcached();
$connection->setOption(memcached::OPT_PREFIX_KEY, 'server1:');
$connection->set("foo", "hello");
```

When I run this code, then take a look in phpmemcachedadmin, I see the key `foo` and not `server1:foo`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

> Memcached::OPT_PREFIX_KEY -
>   This can be used to create a "domain" for your item keys. The value specified here will be prefixed to each of the keys. It cannot be longer than 128 characters and will reduce the maximum available key size. **The prefix is applied only to the item keys, not to the server keys.**

So it seems like the intended behavior... But yes, it looks weird.